# Не удается открыть файл включение: No such file or directory QT CREATOR

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, sfml

Пишу приложение, использую qt creator в качестве ide, и понадобилось мне использовать SFML, но возникла проблема: в `.pro` файл добавил код для подключения SFML:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Никаких ошибок вроде не было, сам qt crator начал видить то, что к SFML  относится:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при попытке сборки проекта я вижу ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни один файл SFML не получается подключить. Что делать?

компилятор MSVC2017 64bit,

SFML 2.5.1 Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 64-bit

Comment: Попробуйте слэши в pro - файле в путях поменять на обратные

Comment: Не забудьте сделать qmake для проекта, после того как поправили его.